# Can you access normal Bluetooth devices with chrome Bluetooth api from webpage ? (no BLE)

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, html

OK, so im doing some research on : How to connect to Bluetooth devices trough a web page.I want the page to prompt a list of paired devices and connect to them.(bluetooth printers). I've found some solutions but i dont want to install anything (like a third party app) on client's PC. I found the google bluetooth api thingy and it works with BLE, the problem is, the device i want to connect doesn't have BLE. I've tryied

```
chrome.bluetooth.getDevices(function(devices) {
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    console.log(devices[i].address);
  }
});
```

for testing purposes in Chrome developer Tools but returns with error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDevices' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:17
```

Dose this API works only on Chrome apps or am i doing something wrong here :D.

Answer (score 0):

As noted at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth, this Chrome Apps API works only on OS X, Windows and Chrome OS.

It looks like you may have missed to include "bluetooth" permission in the manifest.json file. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth

Comment: Okay. From what i've been reading, to access com/usb/bluetooth i need a chrome app. So i need to make an extension that passes data from the webpage to the chrome app. Ia that correct ?